# Upload slow on S3 Bucket for large number of files

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, cloud

I am uploading large numbner of images on AWS s3 bucket via s3 api from my local machine. 800 images gets uploaded in 15  min, but 8000 images take close to 24 hours to upload. Each image is around 10 MB. The time taken to upload increases exponentially with larger number of files.

Transfer acceleration didn't help as I am close to the datacenter location. Multipart upload is recommended for mostly for larger files (>100 MB). What am I missing here ?

Comment: Have you tried uploading the images in parallel?

Comment: @CanArdaAydin, currently playing around with that.  I was uploading 5 images at a time, now trying around with 20. Not looking promising at the moment. I should know for sure in a day or two

Comment: There are many possible reasons. Perhaps your ISP or corporate IT group throttles uploads over a certain size. Perhaps there's something that you're doing in the code that you didn't show (personally, I'm betting on that). I recommend that (1) you measure your actual bandwidth for different-size files using the CLI, and (2) you show us your code.

Comment: One other thing that I'd do is look at the process memory size and swap consumed. Things that slow down when you add more data usually indicate holding on to memory after it's no longer needed.